# Getting an error message of 'undefined' almost each time I try to activate hints

Tags: javascript, html

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Minesweeper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body onload="onInit()">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- ADD TO BODY WHEN TOTALLY FINISHED!!!!!!!!!!! oncontextmenu="disableMenu(event)" -->
        <p class="lives">You have <span></span> lives left</p>
        <p class="best-score">Your best score till now was <span class="reveals"></span> in <span class="seconds"></span> seconds.</p>
        <p class="timer">How much time passed: <span>0</span> seconds</p>
        <p class="hints">
            <img onclick="turnOnHintMode(this)" class="hintImg" src="./icons/hint.png"/></span>
            <img onclick="turnOnHintMode(this)" class="hintImg" src="./icons/hint.png"/></span>
            <img onclick="turnOnHintMode(this)" class="hintImg" src="./icons/hint.png"/></span>
        </p>
        <div class="levels">
            <button onclick="setLevelSize(4, 2)">Beginner</button>
            <button onclick="setLevelSize(8, 14)">Medium</button>
            <button onclick="setLevelSize(12, 32)">Expert</button>
        </div>
        <button class="smiley" onclick="onInit()"><img class="img-button" onmouseup="returnToRegularExpression(this)"
                src="./icons/regular-randy.png" /></button>
        <table>

        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="js/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js"></script>
    <footer>© Made with great love to coding by Tmanoon (Shoval)</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

My JS game file

```
'use strict'

const FLAG = '‍☠️'
const MINE = ''
const EMPTY = ''
var lives = 3
var gSecondsInterval

var gBoard = []

var gLevel = {
    SIZE: 4,
    MINES: 2
}

const gGame = {
    isOn: false,
    shownCount: 0,
    markedCount: 0,
    secsPassed: 0
}

function onInit() {
    if(gSecondsInterval) clearInterval(gSecondsInterval)
    showHints()
    updateLives(lives)
    createBoard()
    renderBoard()
}

function createBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < gLevel.SIZE; i++) {
        gBoard.push([])
        for (let j = 0; j < gLevel.SIZE; j++) {
            const currCell = {
                minesAroundCount: 0,
                isShown: false,
                isMine: false,
                isMarked: false,
                isHint: false,
                wasHinted: false
            }
            gBoard[i][j] = currCell
        }
    }
}

function renderBoard() {
    const board = document.querySelector('table')
    var strHTML = ''
    strHTML += '<tbody>'
    for (let i = 0; i < gLevel.SIZE; i++) {
        strHTML += `<tr>`
        for (let j = 0; j < gLevel.SIZE; j++) {
            const className = `cell ${i}-${j}`
            strHTML += `<td class="${className}" data-i="${i}" data-j="${j}" onmouseup="returnToRegularExpression()" 
            onmousedown="onCellClicked(this, event, ${i}, ${j})">${EMPTY}</td>`
        }
        strHTML += `</tr>`
    }
    strHTML += '</tbody>'
    board.innerHTML = strHTML
}

function onCellClicked(elCell, ev, i, j) {
    const click = ev.button
    gRandyBtn.src = '../icons/anxious-randy.png'

    if (click === 0) {
        if (checkIfFirstClick()) {
            const numOfMines = gLevel.MINES
            onLeftClick(elCell, i, j)
            gGame.shownCount--
            randomMines(numOfMines, i, j)
            setMinesNegsCount(gBoard, i, j)
            onLeftClick(elCell, i, j)
            startCountingSeconds()
            if (gBoard[i][j].isHint) revealCellsAndNegs(i, j)
            return
        }
        if (gBoard[i][j].isHint) revealCellsAndNegs(i, j)
        onLeftClick(elCell, i, j)
    }
    if (click === 2) {
        onCellMarked(elCell)
    }
    return
}

function onLeftClick(elCell, i, j) {
    gGame.shownCount++
    if (gBoard[i][j].isMine) {
        showMine(elCell, i, j)
    }
    else {
        gBoard[i][j].isShown = true
        elCell.innerText = gBoard[i][j].minesAroundCount
    }
}

function showMine(cell, i, j) {
    cell.innerText = MINE
    lives--
    checkIfEnoughLives()
    gRandyBtn.src = '../icons/sad-randy.png'
    gGame.shownCount--
    updateLives(lives)
    gBoard[i][j].isShown = true
    setTimeout(() => {
        cell.innerText = ''
    }, 500)
}

function setMinesNegsCount(board) {
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            const currCell = board[i][j]
            if (currCell.isMine) continue
            currCell.minesAroundCount = countMinesAroundCell(i, j)
        }
    }
}

function countMinesAroundCell(rowIdx, colIdx) {
    var counter = 0
    for (let i = rowIdx - 1; i <= rowIdx + 1; i++) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= gBoard[0].length) continue
        for (let j = colIdx + 1; j >= colIdx - 1; j--) {
            if (j < 0 || j >= gBoard[0].length) continue
            if (gBoard[i][j].isMine) counter++
        }
    }
    return counter
}

function checkGameOver() {
    const winningTotal = (gLevel.SIZE ** 2) - (gLevel.MINES)
    const cellsClickedAndMarked = gGame.shownCount + gGame.markedCount
    if (gGame.secsPassed < 90 && cellsClickedAndMarked === winningTotal) {
        console.log(`You did it! you won!`)
        clearInterval(gSecondsInterval)
    }
    if (gGame.secsPassed >= 90 && cellsClickedAndMarked !== winningTotal) {
        console.log(`Time has run out and you haven't found all the cells yet. You lost.`)
        gRandyBtn.src = '../icons/sad-randy.png'
        clearInterval(gSecondsInterval)
    }
}

function expandShown(board, elCell, i, j) { //try afterwards
}

function randomMines(numOfMines, i, j) {
    while (numOfMines > 0) {
        const iIdxOfRandCell = getRandomIntInclusive()
        const jIdxOfRandCell = getRandomIntInclusive()
        if (gBoard[iIdxOfRandCell][jIdxOfRandCell].isMine === true) continue
        if (iIdxOfRandCell === i && jIdxOfRandCell === j) continue
        gBoard[iIdxOfRandCell][jIdxOfRandCell].isMine = true
        numOfMines--
    }
}

function onCellMarked(elCell) {
    const iIdxOfCell = elCell.dataset.i
    const jIdxOfCell = elCell.dataset.j

    if (gBoard[iIdxOfCell][jIdxOfCell].isMarked === false) {
        elCell.innerText = FLAG
        gGame.markedCount++
        gBoard[iIdxOfCell][jIdxOfCell].isMarked = true
        return
    }
    if (gBoard[iIdxOfCell][jIdxOfCell].isMarked === true) {
        elCell.innerText = EMPTY
        gGame.markedCount--
        gBoard[iIdxOfCell][jIdxOfCell].isMarked = false
    }
}

function checkIfFirstClick() {
    for (let i = 0; i < gBoard.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < gBoard[0].length; j++) {
            const currCell = gBoard[i][j]
            if (currCell.wasHinted || currCell.isShown) return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

function setLevelSize(numForMatrix, numOfMines) {
    gElTimerSpan.innerText = 0
    gGame.secsPassed = 0
    gLevel.SIZE = numForMatrix
    gLevel.MINES = numOfMines
    gBoard = []
    onInit()
}

function updateLives(numOfLives) {
    const spanOfLives = document.querySelector(".lives span")
    spanOfLives.innerText = numOfLives
}

function startCountingSeconds() {
    gSecondsInterval = setInterval(function () {
        timeCounter()
        gGame.secsPassed++
        checkGameOver()
    }, 1000)
}

function checkIfEnoughLives() {
    if (lives === 0) {
        clearInterval(gSecondsInterval)
        gRandyBtn.src = '../icons/sad-randy.png'
        console.log('No more lives. You Lost!')
        onInit()
    }
}

function turnOnHintMode(img) {
    img.style.backgroundColor = 'beige'
    for (let i = 0; i < gBoard.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < gBoard[0].length; j++) {
            gBoard[i][j].isHint = true
        }
    }
}

function revealCellsAndNegs(rowIdx, colIdx) {
    gBoard[rowIdx][colIdx].wasHinted = true
    const originalLives = lives
    for (let i = rowIdx - 1; i <= rowIdx + 1; i++) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= gBoard.length) continue
        for (let j = colIdx + 1; j >= colIdx - 1; j--) {
            if (j < 0 || j >= gBoard[0].length) continue
            const currElCell = document.querySelector(`[data-i="${i}"][data-j="${j}"]`)
            onLeftClick(currElCell ,i, j)
        }
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        unrevealCellAndNegs(rowIdx, colIdx, originalLives)
        turnOffAndRemoveHint()
        turnOffHintMode()
    }, 1000)
    
}

function unrevealCellAndNegs(rowIdx, colIdx, originalLives) {
    for (let i = rowIdx - 1; i <= rowIdx + 1; i++) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= gBoard.length) continue
        for (let j = colIdx + 1; j >= colIdx - 1; j--) {
            if (j < 0 || j >= gBoard[0].length) continue
            const elCell = document.querySelector(`[data-i="${i}"][data-j="${j}"]`)
            elCell.innerText = EMPTY
            lives = originalLives
            updateLives(lives)
            gBoard[i][j].isShown = false
            gGame.shownCount--
        }
    }
    gRandyBtn.src='../icons/regular-randy.png'
}

function turnOffHintMode() {
    for(let i = 0; i < gBoard.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < gBoard[0].length; j++) {
            if(gBoard[i][j].isHint === true) gBoard[i][j].isHint = false
        }
    }
}
```

My utils js file

```
const gRandyBtn = document.querySelector('.img-button')
   const gElTimerSpan = document.querySelector('.timer span')
function getRandomIntInclusive(min = 0, max = gBoard.length - 1) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}

function renderCell(location, value) {
    const cell = document.querySelector(`.cell ${location.i}-${location.j}`)
    cell.innerHTML = value
}

function disableMenu(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
}

function returnToRegularExpression() {
    const img = document.querySelector('.img-button')
    img.src = '../icons/regular-randy.png'
}

function timeCounter() {
 
    gElTimerSpan.innerText = gGame.secsPassed
}

function showHints() {
    const hintsImages = document.querySelectorAll('.hintImg')
    for (let i = 0; i < hintsImages.length; i++) {
        if (hintsImages[i].style.display === 'none') hintsImages[i].style.display = 'inline-block'
    }
}

function turnOffAndRemoveHint() {
        const hintsImages = document.querySelectorAll('.hintImg')
        for (let i = 0; i < hintsImages.length; i++) {
            const currImage = hintsImages[i]
            if (currImage.style.backgroundColor === 'beige') {
                currImage.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
                currImage.style.display = 'none'
            }
        }
}
```

I'm getting this error message many times I use hints , specially in medium and expert levels:

```
game.js:269 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isHint')
    at turnOffHintMode (game.js:269:29)
    at game.js:245:9
turnOffHintMode @ game.js:269
(anonymous) @ game.js:245
setTimeout (async)
revealCellsAndNegs @ game.js:242
onCellClicked @ game.js:78
onmousedown @ index.html:1
```

I tried to debugg it million times using the debugger, tried to find syntax errors, tried to google about such thing.. nothing.
I cannot find out what causes this issue. Please open my eyes.

Debug it and printed the board array almost at each iteration at the function mentioned, googled it, yesterday I sat 5 hours just to try to figure it out myself.

Comment: `gBoard[i][j]` does is `undefined` at some point, so add logs there in your function. It's clear your error is there, it's (at the moment) not syntax related. You are just trying to access something that doesn't exist, so log it all, log `gBoard`, `i` and `j` -and maybe even `gBoard[i]` and see what's missing.

Comment: I did, I did it everytime I clicked and called the hints function.. nothing. I cannot find it.

Comment: the error given is for the reason stated in the above comments.. why it's happening it's because you push items inside the `gBoard` array starting from `onInit` that gets called multiple times inside your page but does get initialized once only at page load. So a possible solution could be to init that array as empty as the first thing you do inside the `onInit` function

Comment: Well, no, a computer doesn't lie - it doesn't know how to lie. It's clearly `gBoard[i][j]` that is missing, so try to manually do what the computer does in your debugging tools, log it, and manually search. Then look where you build this stuff and see if it exists there. Then find every instance that modifies gBoard and log its outcome. Use things like `structuredClone` when logging to _ensure_ that the data you are looking at hasn't been modified later.

Comment: You guys never fail. I found it. After 8 hs trying to understand what was that.. that was it. The lives function.. thank you so much guys for letting me understand that I should check each one separately.

Comment: @Manoon, did you fix your error? please let me know if you fix your error. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The logic error is in the `createBoard()` function.

You used `gBoard.push([])`, please change this to `gBoard[i] = []`.

If you use `gBoard.push([])`, the `gboard`'s length is increased continuously whenever you click the init button.

You will get a greater number than `gLevel.SIZE` for `gBoard.length` in the `turnOffHintMode` function and the `turnOnHintMode` function.

If i is greater than `gLevel.SIZE`, `gBoard[i]` is equal to `[]`, and you will get undefined for `gBoard[i][j]`, so you got you mentioned error.

Here is the updated `createBoard` function:

```
function createBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < gLevel.SIZE; i++) {
        gBoard[i]=[];
        for (let j = 0; j < gLevel.SIZE; j++) {
            const currCell = {
                minesAroundCount: 0,
                isShown: false,
                isMine: false,
                isMarked: false,
                isHint: false,
                wasHinted: false
            };
            gBoard[i][j] = currCell;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use `gLevel.SIZE` instead of `gBoard.length` and `gBoard[i].length` in both of `turnOffHintMode` and `turnOnHintMode` function.

Comment: @Manoon, did you fix your error? please let me know if you fix your error. thanks.

Comment: I did! Ty!!! @Vajilo Torem